# makedirs gives OSError:[Error 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I want to create a folder on apache

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import subprocess
import sys

if not os.path.exists("/home/suni"):
        os.makedirs("/home/suni")
```

But i am unable to do that and facing this error

```
<type 'exceptions.OSError'>: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/suni' 
      args = (13, 'Permission denied') 
      errno = 13 
      filename = '/home/suni' 
      message = '' 
      strerror = 'Permission denied'
```

i have tried `chmod 777 /home`
still facing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Considering Linux filesystem, `/home` directory is tied with `root:root` user.

You should run your python script as root or with `sudo` . Doing `chmod 777` on home directory is not suggested.

Comment: i tried with other directory as well its still not working

Comment: Try to create the directory on the `/tmp`. i.e `os.makedirs("/tmp/suni")`

Comment: Since `/tmp` is working, it confirmed it is the permission issue of the user your python code is running.  Try `os.makedirs(os.getenv("HOME") + "/suni")` .This will create the directory on your Home path. Second option is to give your current user `sudo`  privileges.

Comment: my os.getenv("HOME") is giving None